# Find the how much unique values in a list of vectors - Java

Tags: java

I have to write a code to parse a list of sublist and return how much unique values I have in each subList, I have written this code:

```
public static  Map<Integer,Set<String>>  findAllFrequencies(List<List<String>> data){
    // main key is the column index
    Map<Integer,Set<String>> frequency = new HashMap<>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        List<String> line = data.get(i);
        for (String cell : line) {
            frequency.putIfAbsent(i, Sets.newHashSet(cell));
            frequency.computeIfPresent(i, (k, v) -> {
                v.add(cell);
                return v;
            });
        }
    }
    return frequency;
}
```

Assuming My input is a File and not a List of List is there a better solution?

**The idea is to get a File and parse each columns and find total unique values per column.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking us to review "real" working code belong to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You probably want http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SteveSmith:  No, the OP definitely does not need Code Review.  This is fairly incomplete code as is.

Comment: @GhostCat Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to know if a String is unique in a list of Strings.

1) The lazy solution : use Streams and compute a Map of occurrences of each String :

```
    Map<String, Long> occurrences = strings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

Then, each entry which has a value of 1 is unique.

2) Compute the duplicates and remove all duplicates from the original list :

```
Set<String> alreadySeen = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
for (String s : strings) {
    if(alreadySeen.contains(s)) {
        duplicates.add(s);
    }
    alreadySeen.add(s);
}
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(strings) 
result.removeAll(duplicates);
```

3) If you don't want to create intermediate collections, sort the List. Each element which is different from its predecessor and successor is unique (the cleanest one imho) :

```
Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<>();
strings.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
for(int i = 0; i< strings.size(); i++) {
    String predecessor = i > 0 ? strings.get(i - 1) : null;
    String successor = i < strings.size() - 1 ? strings.get(i + 1) : null;
    String current = strings.get(i);
    if(!current.equals(predecessor) && !current.equals(successor)) {
        uniques.add(current);
    }
}
```